# how do I get maven to tell me what jar it would build without building it?

Tags: maven, maven-3

Given a particular `pom.xml`, maven will build a given package based on the settings.

Is there any way on the command-line I can ask maven to tell me what output file it *would* build, without actually building?

E.g., if part of my pom.xml is

```
<artifactId>foo</artifactId>
<version>0.2.5</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
```

I would want to do something like `mvn package:tell-me-name-without-doing-anything` and get an output like `target/foo-0.2.5.jar`

Comment: This actually depends on lots of things that might be impossible to predict without building. For example, the name can have a [classifier](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/jar-mojo.html#classifier) that could be dynamic... So the bigger question is why do you want to do this?

Comment: That is a good point. I was thinking only about static.

Comment: I want to do it because I might have additional tasks that don't fit within maven (launch Docker container, build node app, etc.), so I want to wrap it in a Makefile... but then I need to extract what the target would be.

Comment: They _could_ fit within Maven, with e.g. [docker-maven-plugin](https://github.com/spotify/docker-maven-plugin) or others... Or build the project with a CI system that invokes those tasks and so it is aware of the Maven artifact. But why do you want to do this _before_ building anything? You can build and work on the built JAR after that.

Comment: I needed it for vars within the Makefile, but I guess it is possible to take the maven output. I would need to be able to know what jar file it _did_ generate.

Comment: Yeah, example I am running `mvn` from within a script, and want to know what jars it _did_ generate so I can use them in some other file.